# Django group by hour/day

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model:

Model.py

```
class DispatchPlan(models.Model):
    total_trucks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0, choices=mtypes)
    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255, default=0)
    offered_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I am trying to plot a graph between scheduled_date and weight. I want to group the timestamp by hour and weight accordingly.
How can I do that?

In SQl its just like `.groupby('scheduled_date)` but since it's a timestamp, I don't think it's the same

Should it be like:

```
data = DispatchPlan.objects.all().groupby('scheduled_date')
```

I am using postgres as my database.

Edit:
 what I tried

```
dataset = DispatchPlan.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('scheduled_date')).values('month').annotate(c=sum('weight')).values('month', 'c')
```

error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Django's `Sum` method instead of Python's `sum`. So do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

dataset = DispatchPlan.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('scheduled_date')).values('month').annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('month', 'c')
```

As it seems you want to group by hour you should be using `TruncHour` instead:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncHour

dataset = DispatchPlan.objects.annotate( 
    hour=TruncHour('scheduled_date')
).values(
    'hour'
).annotate(
    c=Sum('weight')
).values(
    'hour', 
    'c',
)
```

Comment: it gives output as <QuerySet [{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>), 'c': 184000}]> which is for a month, can we get day or hourly data ?