# Select latest record for each hour

Tags: django

I have `Balance` model

Each balance has `b_date = models.DateTimeField()`

I parse balances every 5 mins but to user **I want to show latest balance of each hour**

**So for example**

if I have balances with
`#1 b_date="15:34", #2 b_date="15:55, #3 b_date="20:00"`

the output should be:

```
#2 b_date="10.06.15 15:55 
#3 b_date="11.07.15 20:00"
```

As you can see we removed balance #1 because we need only latest balance from each hour.

So far I've come to this:
`trunc_entries = balances.annotate(tx_hour=TruncHour('b_date'))`
Which sets all hours to 00:00

But I don't know how to group by this tx_hour and select latest

Comment: Can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438461/django-group-by-hour-day

Answer (score 0):

We need to annotate by hour then group by this hour and after that take max of b_date:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncHour
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

# debug balances
# balance1 = Balance.objects.create(b_date=datetime(2020, 3, 10, 15, 34, 0))
# balance2 = Balance.objects.create(b_date=datetime(2020, 3, 10, 15, 55, 0))
# balance3 = Balance.objects.create(b_date=datetime(2020, 3, 10, 20, 00, 0))

balances = Balance.objects \
            .annotate(hour=TruncHour('b_date')) \
            .values('hour') \
            .annotate(tx_hour=Max('b_date'))
```

will print:

```
{'hour': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 20, 0), 'tx_hour': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 20, 0)}
{'hour': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 15, 0), 'tx_hour': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 15, 55)}
```

Comment: i will check it asap

Comment: how do i get list of ids from my balances?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ust7fo
 `balances.annotate(day=TruncDay('b_date')).values('id').annotate(tx_day=Max('b_date')).count()` gives me 3539 results

Comment: while balances.annotate(day=TruncDay('b_date')).values('day').annotate(tx_day=Max('b_date')).count() 
gives me 53 results